# Arabic not rendering in Internet Explorer 9/11 in Windows 7/10

Tags: internet-explorer, language, rendering, arabic

Arabic text is not rendering in IE ( marked in yellow)

But it is showing perfectly in tool tip or the text copied.

I have tried Language settings in IE and Regional Settings in Control Panel. But no hope. It is working perfectly on Chrome and Firefox.

[image]

**Also see the HTML generated. I have noted one more thing, if I remove the italics tag, the text is rendering as Arabic.**

[image]

Comment: Is in the menu "View > Encoding*, do you have Auto select enabled? Try setting it instead to the correct encoding.

Comment: @harrymc I have tried, but no hope.

Comment: Would you have an example HTML posted somewhere?

Comment: @harrymc Please see the HTML returned from server side.

Comment: @harrymc I found one interesting thing. If I remove the <i></i> tag, it displays without any issue.

Comment: The `HTML <i> Tag` means Italics. I don't know if italics exists for Arabic and IE is stupid enough to try, or if the chosen font does not contain correct italics. Do you control this HTML?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95846/discussion-between-rauf-and-harrymc).

Comment: So Arabic does have italicized characters. I need to analyze the real HTML page for real comments.

Comment: Have you tried to install the accurate Arabic font ?

Comment: @marioruiz I have installed artro_Albany.ttf, but no change

Comment: @harrymc The issue is that, it is server generated html. I don't have any control over that.

Comment: If you can see it in the browser, you can save it as complete html and post it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it is not a font system issue as the text is perfectly readable on the dev tool console.

Most probably is about the css style then.

Why you don' try to get another font for your page and from there update your css style accordingly?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371256/how-to-i-use-an-arabic-font-in-my-css